# R: Index matrix row-wise in vectors

Tags: r, list, matrix, indexing

I have a vector containing only character elements, say

```
v <- c("A","B","C")
```

and a matrix containing only logical elements, with width equal to the length of `v` and arbitrary length:

```
> M <- matrix(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
> M
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

Now I would like to index each row of `M` into `v`, collapse, and obtain a vector `r` each element of which contains the corresponding row of `M` in one character expression. In the example given, the elements of `r` would be

```
> r
"A C" "B C"
```

I can do this for each row separately (or within a loop), using

```
r[i] <- paste(v[as.logical(M[i,])], collapse="")
```

but hoped there would be a more efficient solution that deals with the full matrix at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
apply(M, 1, function(x) paste(v[x], collapse=' '))
#[1] "A C" "B C"
```

#### data

```
 M <- matrix(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Great! I would then use `paste(v[x], collapse="")`instead of `toString()` to get rid of the separators.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just noticed that this solution does not permit putting extra elements into the `paste()` command. For instance, `apply(M, 1, function(x)` paste("x+", v[x], collapse=' ')) will add an `x+` to each element, resulting in `r[1] = "x+ A x+ B x+ C"` rather than `r[1] = "x+ A B C"`. Would you know of a work-around?

Comment: @Capsicum Try  `apply(M, 1, function(x) paste('x',paste(v[x], collapse=' '), sep=' + '))#[1] "x + A C" "x + B C"` or just `paste('x', apply(M, 1, function(x) paste(v[x], collapse=' ')), sep=' + ')`